# Scoping Lerna Exec to a specific folder

Tags: lerna, monorepo

I'm using Lerna whilst building a component library using a mono-repo structure. I'd like to create a few new files in a large number of packages, but crucially, not EVERY package.

Ordinary I would run:

```
lerna exec -- touch docs/readme.md
```

or something similar. However I'd like to scope this command to just packages in a sub-directory e.g - packages/molecules.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In a shell:

```sh
# This returns all packages with directory and package name
lerna list --all --parseable --long

# We then grep for your directory name
lerna list --all --parseable --long | grep packages/molecules

# We get just the package name
lerna list --all --parseable --long | grep packages/molecules | cut -d ':' -f 2

# We add the --scope flag to each package name and put it all in one line
lerna list --all --parseable --long | grep packages/molecules | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/^/--scope=/' | xargs

# We now pass all of above into `lerna exec`
lerna exec -- touch docs/readme.md $(yarn lerna list --all --parseable --long | grep packages/molecules | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/^/--scope=/' | xargs)
```

References:

1. [list](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/list#readme)
2. [exec](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/exec#readme)
3. [filters](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/core/filter-options)

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter options [--scope](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/filter-options#--scope-glob) which accept all [filter flags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/filter-options)

> `--scope` Include only packages with names matching the given glob.

E.g.

Create `readme.md` file only in `packages/pkg-a/docs` directory:

```
⚡  npx lerna exec --scope pkg-a -- touch docs/readme.md
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna notice filter including "pkg-a"
lerna info filter [ 'pkg-a' ]
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "touch docs/readme.md"
lerna success exec Executed command in 1 package: "touch docs/readme.md"
```

`lerna` version:

```
⚡  npx lerna -v                                        
3.22.1
```

Comment: Yeah but that is applying it to a specific package. I wanted to run the command on every package in a specified directory. Is that possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. The only filtering option that lerna currently supports is by package name. You can use wildcards if that helps.